# Gitlab post-receive/update hook to forward a commit to another git repo

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks, git-post-receive

In a team we have a gitlab set up that is avialable only to our team and is meant for development purposes, pushing, branching etc and we have an official git repo to which we would like to mirror commits only from master branch (stable).

I know that this can be done with use of server-side git hooks but how specifically can I do that so that the developers won't have to type anything extra and the hook will be set on gitlab (no on developers' machines - local repos) ?

Comment: // , Did the answer end up working?

Comment: @NathanBasanese Yes it did as I have written so in the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961419/gitlab-post-receive-update-hook-to-forward-a-commit-to-another-git-repo?noredirect=1#comment44325249_27963522) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this recipe](http://krisjordan.com/essays/setting-up-push-to-deploy-with-git). In the recipe the author propagates changes being pushed to the master to a working tree, you need to replace that part of the code with another `git push` to your public server.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I needed:) Although I may rewrite the hook script to python since no need to install ruby specially for this few lines of code .

Comment: I would do the same :-) Or even stay with plain bash, since the logic is rather simple :)