# Synchronizing two different git repos hosted on different git servers

Tags: git, gitlab, drone.io

I have two different git repositories hosted on two different gitlab servers say `gitrepo1` and `gitrepo2`

`gitrepo2` has CI configured to it (drone.io), so any updates to this repo automatically builds the code and performs some other tasks.

However, there is not CI configured for `gitrepo1` and my source code is located in this repo and I want to use the same CI functionality for this repo too.

I want to ask the following questions:

1. Is it ok to automatically set a trigger to update `gitrepo2` when `gitrepo` changes?
2. If yes, then, what's the best way to do it?
3. If no, then how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

A [mirroring repo](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html) might be overkill (and available only in the Enterprise edition of GitLab anyway)

So a simple [custom hook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/custom_hooks.html) would be enough: a post-receive one which, on reception of commits, would push them to a matching branch to the second repo on the second server.
See for instance "[Gitlab post-receive/update hook to forward a commit to another git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27963522/6309)".